# An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could not be found in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I want to update record from `FormView` with `ObjectDataSource` and lose my day to solve this error.

> An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could
>   not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the key values of
>   the supplied object match the key values of the object to which
>   changes must be applied.

My code is below

```
private static Entities1 _db = null;

public static Entities1 CreateDataContext()
{
    if (_db == null)
    {
        _db = new Entities1(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities1"].ConnectionString);
        _db.games.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
        _db.my_aspnet_users.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
        _db.platforms.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
    }
    return _db;
}

public void Update(game item)
{
    Entities1 DB = CreateDataContext();
    item.modified = DateTime.Now;
    var obj = (from u in DB.games
               where u.idgames == item.idgames
               select u).First();
    DB.games.ApplyCurrentValues(item);//Error Here
    DB.SaveChanges();         
}
```

Comment: `var obj` is unused; is this by design?

Answer (score 6):

In your method:

```
public void Update(game item)
{
    Entities1 DB = CreateDataContext();
    item.modified = DateTime.Now;
    var obj = (from u in DB.games
               where u.idgames == item.idgames
               select u).First();
    DB.games.ApplyCurrentValues(item);//Error Here
    DB.SaveChanges();         
}
```

`item` is not attached so it can't be updated. That's pretty much what the error message is telling you, too.

It looks like you'd want to use `obj` which is retrieved from your context. Then set the values of `obj` to those in `item`, and use `obj` to make the updates.

**EDIT for sample**...

If you just want to set the modified date and time you'd do this:

```
public void Update(game item) {
    Entities1 DB = CreateDataContext();

    var obj = (from u in DB.games
               where u.idgames == item.idgames
               select u).SingleOrDefault();
    if (obj == null) {
      // handle the case where obj isn't found
      // probably by throwing an exception
    }

    obj.modified = DateTime.Now;
    DB.games.ApplyCurrentValues(obj);
    DB.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271(v=VS.100).aspx In general you will call `Attach()` or you can query the context for an object which will return it in the attached state. For instance, `obj` in your example will come back attached.

Comment: i have many Classes which was created in nhibernat so now i am converting all to .Net 4.0. if i create obj and ill pass manually then it ill time consume process. I want to update only with item coming from ObjectDataSource.

Comment: Hi Yuck, Please can you give me a good example to attach. i tried some samples but failed. thanks

Comment: thanks to reply. Update(game item)....item Object holds all changes it has also childs tables which are changed from objectdatasource. so then i want to update that item object rather than obj.

Comment: Then `Attach(item)` and don't bother bringing `obj` into the state manager.

Comment: i try to attach.  DB.games.Attach(item);......it throws exception....A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.